# ModuleNotFound Error on sklearn while trying to install it via the terminal using pip with no virtual environment. So whenever i run the cell, error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, pip

I wanted to build a simple model that does Linear and Polynomial regression so I have to have `sklearn` imports. So I installed the packages using `pip install scikit-learn` and `pip install sklearn` and they get installed successfully. But when I run the cell containing the imports (I am writing in Jupyter Notebook) it still doesn't find the module `sklearn`.

I tried uninstalling and installing the packages one by one, I tried installing them as if in a requirements.txt file so I have no idea what else to do.

Comment: Try to run `python -c "import sklearn"` in the terminal to see if it's possible to import directly in the terminal. And run `pip list` or `pip freeze` in the terminal to ensure `scikit-learn` is listed among installed packages.

Comment: Often to insure the installations are done in the environment where kernel backing your active Jupyter is running, you can install from **within** the running `.ipynb` file with the magic versions of the install commands. Try making a new cell in your notebook where you want to import and run `%pip install sklearn scikit-learn`. Restart the kernel after that runs in its entirety and then try the import commands. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often to insure the installations are done in the environment where kernel backing your active Jupyter is running, you can install from within the running `.ipynb` file with the magic versions of the install commands. Try making a new cell in your notebook where you want to import and run `%pip install sklearn scikit-learn`. Restart the kernel after that runs in its entirety and then try the import commands. [See here for more about the magic install commands](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303?u=fomightez).

This was @Wayne solution in the comments.